# Color output problems in cmd

Tags: perl, cmd, ansi-escape

Here is the code:

```
use Cwd;
use Win32::Console::ANSI;# installed module with ppm
use Term::ANSIColor;

$parent =  cwd();

@files = <*>;
print "\n";
foreach (@files)
{
    $child = "$parent/$_";
    if (-f $_){print "$child\n";}; #file test
    if (-d $_)#directory test
    {
        print color("green")."$child/\n".color("reset");
        my($command) = "cd $child/";#submerge one directory down ( recursive here?)
        $command=~s/\//\\/g;
        system( $command );
    };
}
```

The problem I have is with the way output gets colored.
What I am expecting to get is "some directory" in green on black background.
Instead I get background color in green and text in black, sometimes white randomly.
I have this problem on every other code where I use color().
I noticed the problem goes away after I restart. 
Also, my suspicion is that the problem returns affecting DOS and all its windows when I run some other perl code. Basically, once it goes wrong it is there until restart for every instance of color(). It looks like a glitch. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not observe the problem. However, the fact that you are using `system` (which starts a different shell to carry out the command and therefore really does not change your directory) may be what's interfering. Alternatively, the console might be left in an indeterminate state if you are using <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> to break out of the script.

Here is a better way of accomplishing what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Cwd;
use File::Spec::Functions qw( catfile canonpath );
use Win32::Console::ANSI;
use Term::ANSIColor;

local $SIG{INT} = sub { print color('reset') };

my $top = cwd;

print_contents($top);

sub print_contents {
    my ($dir) = @_;

    opendir my $dir_h, $dir
        or die "Cannot open directory: '$dir': $!";

    while ( defined (my $entry = readdir $dir_h) ) {
        next if $entry =~ /^[.][.]?\z/;
        my $path = canonpath catfile $dir => $entry;
        if ( -f $path ) {
            print "$path\n";
        }
        elsif ( -d $path ) {
            print color('green'), $path, color('reset'), "\n";
            print_contents($path);
        }
    }

    closedir $dir_h
        or die "Cannot close directory: '$dir': $!";
}
```

Comment: Okay, in that case it's not my code its something else. It is very strange that I do not get the color that my program requests. Hopefully, someone who has similar experience will find this and help. Also, I do not want the code that depends on modules that don't come with my default compiler. Your code requires File::Spec::Functions, good try...

Comment: @seaworthy: First: `File::Spec::Functions` is in the core. Second, I guess you prefer to drive with a trapezoidal wheel rather than a round one. *Sigh*